# Proper way to deal with HtmlUnit warnings about invalid CSS in Bootstrap 4?

Tags: bootstrap-4, htmlunit

HtmlUnit doesn't like Bootstrap 4:

```
15:06:26 WARNING: CSS error: 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css' [6:10] Error in style rule. (Invalid token "-". Was expecting one of: <EOF>, <S>, <IDENT>, "}", ";", "*".) @com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error 
15:06:26 WARNING: CSS warning: 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css' [6:10] Ignoring the following declarations in this rule. @com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler warning 
15:06:26 WARNING: CSS error: 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css' [6:25994] Error in expression. (Invalid token " ". Was expecting one of: <NUMBER>, "inherit", <IDENT>, <STRING>, <HASH>, <EMS>, <REM>, <EXS>, <LENGTH_PX>, <LENGTH_CM>, <LENGTH_MM>, <LENGTH_IN>, <LENGTH_PT>, <LENGTH_PC>, <ANGLE_DEG>, <ANGLE_RAD>, <ANGLE_GRAD>, <TIME_MS>, <TIME_S>, <FREQ_HZ>, <FREQ_KHZ>, <RESOLUTION_DPI>, <RESOLUTION_DPCM>, <PERCENTAGE>, <DIMENSION>, <UNICODE_RANGE>, <URI>, <FUNCTION>, "progid:".) @com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error 
15:06:26 WARNING: CSS error: 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css' [6:26179] Error in expression. (Invalid token " ". Was expecting one of: <NUMBER>, "inherit", <IDENT>, <STRING>, <HASH>, <EMS>, <REM>, <EXS>, <LENGTH_PX>, <LENGTH_CM>, <LENGTH_MM>, <LENGTH_IN>, <LENGTH_PT>, <LENGTH_PC>, <ANGLE_DEG>, <ANGLE_RAD>, <ANGLE_GRAD>, <TIME_MS>, <TIME_S>, <FREQ_HZ>, <FREQ_KHZ>, <RESOLUTION_DPI>, <RESOLUTION_DPCM>, <PERCENTAGE>, <DIMENSION>, <UNICODE_RANGE>, <URI>, <FUNCTION>, "progid:".) @com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error 
15:06:26 WARNING: CSS error: 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css' [6:26214] Error in expression. (Invalid token " ". Was expecting one of: <NUMBER>, "inherit", <IDENT>, <STRING>, <HASH>, <EMS>, <REM>, <EXS>, <LENGTH_PX>, <LENGTH_CM>, <LENGTH_MM>, <LENGTH_IN>, <LENGTH_PT>, <LENGTH_PC>, <ANGLE_DEG>, <ANGLE_RAD>, <ANGLE_GRAD>, <TIME_MS>, <TIME_S>, <FREQ_HZ>, <FREQ_KHZ>, <RESOLUTION_DPI>, <RESOLUTION_DPCM>, <PERCENTAGE>, <DIMENSION>, <UNICODE_RANGE>, <URI>, <FUNCTION>, "progid:".) @com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error 
15:06:26 WARNING: CSS error: 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css' [6:26313] Error in expression. (Invalid token " ". Was expecting one of: <NUMBER>, "inherit", <IDENT>, <STRING>, <HASH>, <EMS>, <REM>, <EXS>, <LENGTH_PX>, <LENGTH_CM>, <LENGTH_MM>, <LENGTH_IN>, <LENGTH_PT>, <LENGTH_PC>, <ANGLE_DEG>, <ANGLE_RAD>, <ANGLE_GRAD>, <TIME_MS>, <TIME_S>, <FREQ_HZ>, <FREQ_KHZ>, <RESOLUTION_DPI>, <RESOLUTION_DPCM>, <PERCENTAGE>, <DIMENSION>, <UNICODE_RANGE>, <URI>, <FUNCTION>, "progid:".) @com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error 
15:06:26 WARNING: CSS error: 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css' [6:26346] Error in expression. (Invalid token " ". Was expecting one of: <NUMBER>, "inherit", <IDENT>, <STRING>, <HASH>, <EMS>, <REM>, <EXS>, <LENGTH_PX>, <LENGTH_CM>, <LENGTH_MM>, <LENGTH_IN>, <LENGTH_PT>, <LENGTH_PC>, <ANGLE_DEG>, <ANGLE_RAD>, <ANGLE_GRAD>, <TIME_MS>, <TIME_S>, <FREQ_HZ>, <FREQ_KHZ>, <RESOLUTION_DPI>, <RESOLUTION_DPCM>, <PERCENTAGE>, <DIMENSION>, <UNICODE_RANGE>, <URI>, <FUNCTION>, "progid:".) @com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error 
15:06:26 WARNING: CSS error: 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css' [6:26430] Error in expression. (Invalid token " ". Was expecting one of: <NUMBER>, "inherit", <IDENT>, <STRING>, <HASH>, <EMS>, <REM>, <EXS>, <LENGTH_PX>, <LENGTH_CM>, <LENGTH_MM>, <LENGTH_IN>, <LENGTH_PT>, <LENGTH_PC>, <ANGLE_DEG>, <ANGLE_RAD>, <ANGLE_GRAD>, <TIME_MS>, <TIME_S>, <FREQ_HZ>, <FREQ_KHZ>, <RESOLUTION_DPI>, <RESOLUTION_DPCM>, <PERCENTAGE>, <DIMENSION>, <UNICODE_RANGE>, <URI>, <FUNCTION>, "progid:".) @com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error 
15:06:26 WARNING: CSS error: 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css' [6:26464] Error in expression. (Invalid token " ". Was expecting one of: <NUMBER>, "inherit", <IDENT>, <STRING>, <HASH>, <EMS>, <REM>, <EXS>, <LENGTH_PX>, <LENGTH_CM>, <LENGTH_MM>, <LENGTH_IN>, <LENGTH_PT>, <LENGTH_PC>, <ANGLE_DEG>, <ANGLE_RAD>, <ANGLE_GRAD>, <TIME_MS>, <TIME_S>, <FREQ_HZ>, <FREQ_KHZ>, <RESOLUTION_DPI>, <RESOLUTION_DPCM>, <PERCENTAGE>, <DIMENSION>, <UNICODE_RANGE>, <URI>, <FUNCTION>, "progid:".) @com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error 
15:06:26 WARNING: CSS error: 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css' [6:28266] Error in expression. (Invalid token " ". Was expecting one of: <NUMBER>, "inherit", <IDENT>, <STRING>, <HASH>, <EMS>, <REM>, <EXS>, <LENGTH_PX>, <LENGTH_CM>, <LENGTH_MM>, <LENGTH_IN>, <LENGTH_PT>, <LENGTH_PC>, <ANGLE_DEG>, <ANGLE_RAD>, <ANGLE_GRAD>, <TIME_MS>, <TIME_S>, <FREQ_HZ>, <FREQ_KHZ>, <RESOLUTION_DPI>, <RESOLUTION_DPCM>, <PERCENTAGE>, <DIMENSION>, <UNICODE_RANGE>, <URI>, <FUNCTION>, "progid:".) @com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error 
15:06:26 WARNING: CSS error: 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css' [6:29049] Error in expression. (Invalid token " ". Was expecting one of: <NUMBER>, "inherit", <IDENT>, <STRING>, <HASH>, <EMS>, <REM>, <EXS>, <LENGTH_PX>, <LENGTH_CM>, <LENGTH_MM>, <LENGTH_IN>, <LENGTH_PT>, <LENGTH_PC>, <ANGLE_DEG>, <ANGLE_RAD>, <ANGLE_GRAD>, <TIME_MS>, <TIME_S>, <FREQ_HZ>, <FREQ_KHZ>, <RESOLUTION_DPI>, <RESOLUTION_DPCM>, <PERCENTAGE>, <DIMENSION>, <UNICODE_RANGE>, <URI>, <FUNCTION>, "progid:".) @com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error 
15:06:26 WARNING: CSS error: 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css' [6:63092] Error in expression. (Invalid token " ". Was expecting one of: <NUMBER>, "inherit", <IDENT>, <STRING>, <HASH>, <EMS>, <REM>, <EXS>, <LENGTH_PX>, <LENGTH_CM>, <LENGTH_MM>, <LENGTH_IN>, <LENGTH_PT>, <LENGTH_PC>, <ANGLE_DEG>, <ANGLE_RAD>, <ANGLE_GRAD>, <TIME_MS>, <TIME_S>, <FREQ_HZ>, <FREQ_KHZ>, <RESOLUTION_DPI>, <RESOLUTION_DPCM>, <PERCENTAGE>, <DIMENSION>, <UNICODE_RANGE>, <URI>, <FUNCTION>, "progid:".) @com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error 
15:06:26 WARNING: CSS error: 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css' [6:63985] Error in expression. (Invalid token " ". Was expecting one of: <NUMBER>, "inherit", <IDENT>, <STRING>, <HASH>, <EMS>, <REM>, <EXS>, <LENGTH_PX>, <LENGTH_CM>, <LENGTH_MM>, <LENGTH_IN>, <LENGTH_PT>, <LENGTH_PC>, <ANGLE_DEG>, <ANGLE_RAD>, <ANGLE_GRAD>, <TIME_MS>, <TIME_S>, <FREQ_HZ>, <FREQ_KHZ>, <RESOLUTION_DPI>, <RESOLUTION_DPCM>, <PERCENTAGE>, <DIMENSION>, <UNICODE_RANGE>, <URI>, <FUNCTION>, "progid:".) @com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error 
15:06:26 WARNING: CSS error: 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css' [6:64088] Error in expression. (Invalid token " ". Was expecting one of: <NUMBER>, "inherit", <IDENT>, <STRING>, <HASH>, <EMS>, <REM>, <EXS>, <LENGTH_PX>, <LENGTH_CM>, <LENGTH_MM>, <LENGTH_IN>, <LENGTH_PT>, <LENGTH_PC>, <ANGLE_DEG>, <ANGLE_RAD>, <ANGLE_GRAD>, <TIME_MS>, <TIME_S>, <FREQ_HZ>, <FREQ_KHZ>, <RESOLUTION_DPI>, <RESOLUTION_DPCM>, <PERCENTAGE>, <DIMENSION>, <UNICODE_RANGE>, <URI>, <FUNCTION>, "progid:".) @com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error 
15:06:26 WARNING: CSS error: 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css' [6:64236] Error in expression. (Invalid token " ". Was expecting one of: <NUMBER>, "inherit", <IDENT>, <STRING>, <HASH>, <EMS>, <REM>, <EXS>, <LENGTH_PX>, <LENGTH_CM>, <LENGTH_MM>, <LENGTH_IN>, <LENGTH_PT>, <LENGTH_PC>, <ANGLE_DEG>, <ANGLE_RAD>, <ANGLE_GRAD>, <TIME_MS>, <TIME_S>, <FREQ_HZ>, <FREQ_KHZ>, <RESOLUTION_DPI>, <RESOLUTION_DPCM>, <PERCENTAGE>, <DIMENSION>, <UNICODE_RANGE>, <URI>, <FUNCTION>, "progid:".) @com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error 
15:06:26 WARNING: CSS error: 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css' [6:64337] Error in expression. (Invalid token " ". Was expecting one of: <NUMBER>, "inherit", <IDENT>, <STRING>, <HASH>, <EMS>, <REM>, <EXS>, <LENGTH_PX>, <LENGTH_CM>, <LENGTH_MM>, <LENGTH_IN>, <LENGTH_PT>, <LENGTH_PC>, <ANGLE_DEG>, <ANGLE_RAD>, <ANGLE_GRAD>, <TIME_MS>, <TIME_S>, <FREQ_HZ>, <FREQ_KHZ>, <RESOLUTION_DPI>, <RESOLUTION_DPCM>, <PERCENTAGE>, <DIMENSION>, <UNICODE_RANGE>, <URI>, <FUNCTION>, "progid:".) @com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error 
15:06:26 WARNING: CSS error: 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css' [6:64707] Error in expression. (Invalid token " ". Was expecting one of: <NUMBER>, "inherit", <IDENT>, <STRING>, <HASH>, <EMS>, <REM>, <EXS>, <LENGTH_PX>, <LENGTH_CM>, <LENGTH_MM>, <LENGTH_IN>, <LENGTH_PT>, <LENGTH_PC>, <ANGLE_DEG>, <ANGLE_RAD>, <ANGLE_GRAD>, <TIME_MS>, <TIME_S>, <FREQ_HZ>, <FREQ_KHZ>, <RESOLUTION_DPI>, <RESOLUTION_DPCM>, <PERCENTAGE>, <DIMENSION>, <UNICODE_RANGE>, <URI>, <FUNCTION>, "progid:".) @com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error 
15:06:26 WARNING: CSS error: 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css' [6:64951] Error in expression. (Invalid token " ". Was expecting one of: <NUMBER>, "inherit", <IDENT>, <STRING>, <HASH>, <EMS>, <REM>, <EXS>, <LENGTH_PX>, <LENGTH_CM>, <LENGTH_MM>, <LENGTH_IN>, <LENGTH_PT>, <LENGTH_PC>, <ANGLE_DEG>, <ANGLE_RAD>, <ANGLE_GRAD>, <TIME_MS>, <TIME_S>, <FREQ_HZ>, <FREQ_KHZ>, <RESOLUTION_DPI>, <RESOLUTION_DPCM>, <PERCENTAGE>, <DIMENSION>, <UNICODE_RANGE>, <URI>, <FUNCTION>, "progid:".) @com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error 
15:06:26 WARNING: CSS error: 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css' [6:76681] Error in expression. (Invalid token " ". Was expecting one of: <NUMBER>, "inherit", <IDENT>, <STRING>, <HASH>, <EMS>, <REM>, <EXS>, <LENGTH_PX>, <LENGTH_CM>, <LENGTH_MM>, <LENGTH_IN>, <LENGTH_PT>, <LENGTH_PC>, <ANGLE_DEG>, <ANGLE_RAD>, <ANGLE_GRAD>, <TIME_MS>, <TIME_S>, <FREQ_HZ>, <FREQ_KHZ>, <RESOLUTION_DPI>, <RESOLUTION_DPCM>, <PERCENTAGE>, <DIMENSION>, <UNICODE_RANGE>, <URI>, <FUNCTION>, "progid:".) @com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error 
15:06:26 WARNING: CSS error: 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css' [6:76939] Error in expression. (Invalid token " ". Was expecting one of: <NUMBER>, "inherit", <IDENT>, <STRING>, <HASH>, <EMS>, <REM>, <EXS>, <LENGTH_PX>, <LENGTH_CM>, <LENGTH_MM>, <LENGTH_IN>, <LENGTH_PT>, <LENGTH_PC>, <ANGLE_DEG>, <ANGLE_RAD>, <ANGLE_GRAD>, <TIME_MS>, <TIME_S>, <FREQ_HZ>, <FREQ_KHZ>, <RESOLUTION_DPI>, <RESOLUTION_DPCM>, <PERCENTAGE>, <DIMENSION>, <UNICODE_RANGE>, <URI>, <FUNCTION>, "progid:".) @com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error 
15:06:26 WARNING: CSS error: 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css' [6:77255] Error in expression. (Invalid token " ". Was expecting one of: <NUMBER>, "inherit", <IDENT>, <STRING>, <HASH>, <EMS>, <REM>, <EXS>, <LENGTH_PX>, <LENGTH_CM>, <LENGTH_MM>, <LENGTH_IN>, <LENGTH_PT>, <LENGTH_PC>, <ANGLE_DEG>, <ANGLE_RAD>, <ANGLE_GRAD>, <TIME_MS>, <TIME_S>, <FREQ_HZ>, <FREQ_KHZ>, <RESOLUTION_DPI>, <RESOLUTION_DPCM>, <PERCENTAGE>, <DIMENSION>, <UNICODE_RANGE>, <URI>, <FUNCTION>, "progid:".) @com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error 
15:06:26 WARNING: CSS error: 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css' [6:77322] Error in expression. (Invalid token " ". Was expecting one of: <NUMBER>, "inherit", <IDENT>, <STRING>, <HASH>, <EMS>, <REM>, <EXS>, <LENGTH_PX>, <LENGTH_CM>, <LENGTH_MM>, <LENGTH_IN>, <LENGTH_PT>, <LENGTH_PC>, <ANGLE_DEG>, <ANGLE_RAD>, <ANGLE_GRAD>, <TIME_MS>, <TIME_S>, <FREQ_HZ>, <FREQ_KHZ>, <RESOLUTION_DPI>, <RESOLUTION_DPCM>, <PERCENTAGE>, <DIMENSION>, <UNICODE_RANGE>, <URI>, <FUNCTION>, "progid:".) @com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error 
15:06:26 WARNING: CSS error: 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css' [6:77365] Error in expression. (Invalid token " ". Was expecting one of: <NUMBER>, "inherit", <IDENT>, <STRING>, <HASH>, <EMS>, <REM>, <EXS>, <LENGTH_PX>, <LENGTH_CM>, <LENGTH_MM>, <LENGTH_IN>, <LENGTH_PT>, <LENGTH_PC>, <ANGLE_DEG>, <ANGLE_RAD>, <ANGLE_GRAD>, <TIME_MS>, <TIME_S>, <FREQ_HZ>, <FREQ_KHZ>, <RESOLUTION_DPI>, <RESOLUTION_DPCM>, <PERCENTAGE>, <DIMENSION>, <UNICODE_RANGE>, <URI>, <FUNCTION>, "progid:".) @com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error 
15:06:26 WARNING: CSS error: 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css' [6:77439] Error in expression. (Invalid token " ". Was expecting one of: <NUMBER>, "inherit", <IDENT>, <STRING>, <HASH>, <EMS>, <REM>, <EXS>, <LENGTH_PX>, <LENGTH_CM>, <LENGTH_MM>, <LENGTH_IN>, <LENGTH_PT>, <LENGTH_PC>, <ANGLE_DEG>, <ANGLE_RAD>, <ANGLE_GRAD>, <TIME_MS>, <TIME_S>, <FREQ_HZ>, <FREQ_KHZ>, <RESOLUTION_DPI>, <RESOLUTION_DPCM>, <PERCENTAGE>, <DIMENSION>, <UNICODE_RANGE>, <URI>, <FUNCTION>, "progid:".) @com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error 
15:06:26 WARNING: CSS error: 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css' [6:77484] Error in expression. (Invalid token " ". Was expecting one of: <NUMBER>, "inherit", <IDENT>, <STRING>, <HASH>, <EMS>, <REM>, <EXS>, <LENGTH_PX>, <LENGTH_CM>, <LENGTH_MM>, <LENGTH_IN>, <LENGTH_PT>, <LENGTH_PC>, <ANGLE_DEG>, <ANGLE_RAD>, <ANGLE_GRAD>, <TIME_MS>, <TIME_S>, <FREQ_HZ>, <FREQ_KHZ>, <RESOLUTION_DPI>, <RESOLUTION_DPCM>, <PERCENTAGE>, <DIMENSION>, <UNICODE_RANGE>, <URI>, <FUNCTION>, "progid:".) @com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error 
15:06:26 WARNING: CSS error: 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css' [6:91815] Error in expression. (Invalid token " ". Was expecting one of: <NUMBER>, "inherit", <IDENT>, <STRING>, <HASH>, <EMS>, <REM>, <EXS>, <LENGTH_PX>, <LENGTH_CM>, <LENGTH_MM>, <LENGTH_IN>, <LENGTH_PT>, <LENGTH_PC>, <ANGLE_DEG>, <ANGLE_RAD>, <ANGLE_GRAD>, <TIME_MS>, <TIME_S>, <FREQ_HZ>, <FREQ_KHZ>, <RESOLUTION_DPI>, <RESOLUTION_DPCM>, <PERCENTAGE>, <DIMENSION>, <UNICODE_RANGE>, <URI>, <FUNCTION>, "progid:".) @com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error 
15:06:26 WARNING: CSS error: 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css' [6:93398] Error in expression. (Invalid token " ". Was expecting one of: <NUMBER>, "inherit", <IDENT>, <STRING>, <HASH>, <EMS>, <REM>, <EXS>, <LENGTH_PX>, <LENGTH_CM>, <LENGTH_MM>, <LENGTH_IN>, <LENGTH_PT>, <LENGTH_PC>, <ANGLE_DEG>, <ANGLE_RAD>, <ANGLE_GRAD>, <TIME_MS>, <TIME_S>, <FREQ_HZ>, <FREQ_KHZ>, <RESOLUTION_DPI>, <RESOLUTION_DPCM>, <PERCENTAGE>, <DIMENSION>, <UNICODE_RANGE>, <URI>, <FUNCTION>, "progid:".) @com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error 
15:06:26 WARNING: CSS error: 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css' [6:96505] Error in expression. (Invalid token "(". Was expecting one of: <S>, <NUMBER>, "inherit", <IDENT>, <STRING>, ")", "-", <PLUS>, <HASH>, <EMS>, <REM>, <EXS>, <LENGTH_PX>, <LENGTH_CM>, <LENGTH_MM>, <LENGTH_IN>, <LENGTH_PT>, <LENGTH_PC>, <ANGLE_DEG>, <ANGLE_RAD>, <ANGLE_GRAD>, <TIME_MS>, <TIME_S>, <FREQ_HZ>, <FREQ_KHZ>, <RESOLUTION_DPI>, <RESOLUTION_DPCM>, <PERCENTAGE>, <DIMENSION>, <UNICODE_RANGE>, <URI>, <FUNCTION>, "progid:".) @com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error 
15:06:26 WARNING: CSS error: 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css' [6:97099] Error in expression. (Invalid token "(". Was expecting one of: <S>, <NUMBER>, "inherit", <IDENT>, <STRING>, ")", "-", <PLUS>, <HASH>, <EMS>, <REM>, <EXS>, <LENGTH_PX>, <LENGTH_CM>, <LENGTH_MM>, <LENGTH_IN>, <LENGTH_PT>, <LENGTH_PC>, <ANGLE_DEG>, <ANGLE_RAD>, <ANGLE_GRAD>, <TIME_MS>, <TIME_S>, <FREQ_HZ>, <FREQ_KHZ>, <RESOLUTION_DPI>, <RESOLUTION_DPCM>, <PERCENTAGE>, <DIMENSION>, <UNICODE_RANGE>, <URI>, <FUNCTION>, "progid:".) @com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error 
15:06:26 WARNING: CSS error: 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css' [6:97756] Error in expression. (Invalid token "(". Was expecting one of: <S>, <NUMBER>, "inherit", <IDENT>, <STRING>, ")", "-", <PLUS>, <HASH>, <EMS>, <REM>, <EXS>, <LENGTH_PX>, <LENGTH_CM>, <LENGTH_MM>, <LENGTH_IN>, <LENGTH_PT>, <LENGTH_PC>, <ANGLE_DEG>, <ANGLE_RAD>, <ANGLE_GRAD>, <TIME_MS>, <TIME_S>, <FREQ_HZ>, <FREQ_KHZ>, <RESOLUTION_DPI>, <RESOLUTION_DPCM>, <PERCENTAGE>, <DIMENSION>, <UNICODE_RANGE>, <URI>, <FUNCTION>, "progid:".) @com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error 
15:06:26 WARNING: CSS error: 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css' [6:98603] Error in expression. (Invalid token "(". Was expecting one of: <S>, <NUMBER>, "inherit", <IDENT>, <STRING>, ")", "-", <PLUS>, <HASH>, <EMS>, <REM>, <EXS>, <LENGTH_PX>, <LENGTH_CM>, <LENGTH_MM>, <LENGTH_IN>, <LENGTH_PT>, <LENGTH_PC>, <ANGLE_DEG>, <ANGLE_RAD>, <ANGLE_GRAD>, <TIME_MS>, <TIME_S>, <FREQ_HZ>, <FREQ_KHZ>, <RESOLUTION_DPI>, <RESOLUTION_DPCM>, <PERCENTAGE>, <DIMENSION>, <UNICODE_RANGE>, <URI>, <FUNCTION>, "progid:".) @com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error 
15:06:26 WARNING: CSS error: 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css' [6:99272] Error in expression. (Invalid token " ". Was expecting one of: <NUMBER>, "inherit", <IDENT>, <STRING>, <HASH>, <EMS>, <REM>, <EXS>, <LENGTH_PX>, <LENGTH_CM>, <LENGTH_MM>, <LENGTH_IN>, <LENGTH_PT>, <LENGTH_PC>, <ANGLE_DEG>, <ANGLE_RAD>, <ANGLE_GRAD>, <TIME_MS>, <TIME_S>, <FREQ_HZ>, <FREQ_KHZ>, <RESOLUTION_DPI>, <RESOLUTION_DPCM>, <PERCENTAGE>, <DIMENSION>, <UNICODE_RANGE>, <URI>, <FUNCTION>, "progid:".) @com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error 
15:06:26 WARNING: CSS error: 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css' [6:99314] Error in expression. (Invalid token " ". Was expecting one of: <NUMBER>, "inherit", <IDENT>, <STRING>, <HASH>, <EMS>, <REM>, <EXS>, <LENGTH_PX>, <LENGTH_CM>, <LENGTH_MM>, <LENGTH_IN>, <LENGTH_PT>, <LENGTH_PC>, <ANGLE_DEG>, <ANGLE_RAD>, <ANGLE_GRAD>, <TIME_MS>, <TIME_S>, <FREQ_HZ>, <FREQ_KHZ>, <RESOLUTION_DPI>, <RESOLUTION_DPCM>, <PERCENTAGE>, <DIMENSION>, <UNICODE_RANGE>, <URI>, <FUNCTION>, "progid:".) @com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
```

What is the **proper** way to deal with this? Can I shutoff warnings for just **bootstrap.min.css**?

I don't want to disable all warnings; I find it helpful to see warnings about CSS in my own project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write your own implementation of com.gargoylesoftware.css.parser.CSSErrorHandler and register it at the WebClient.

In your implementation you can check the uri of the CSSParseExceptions and log only if the exception is not from the bootstrap file.

For your implementation you can subclass or decorate the com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler if you like.